# Disable delete icon for first entry in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I have an code in which I want to disable the "delete icon" for the first entry. The first entry is "English".

The list contains the data: English, Chinese, German, etc.. The delete icon is to be placed for other languages, but for english which is the first entry, should be disabled.

Below is the html code:

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="form-group col-md-3">Language</label>
                    <label class="form-group col-md-4">Title</label>
                    <label class="form-group col-md-5"> Description</label>
                </div>
            </div> 
<div class="row">
   <div>
                        <div ng-repeat="Descriptions in mainsWithDescription ">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
                                <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control input-md" name="titleValidate[]" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">                             
                                <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" name="descriptionValidate[]" noresize ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <a style="cursor:pointer"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': ($index == !selected)}" /> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If english is always first, you can use the `$first` scope variable that is automatically created by the `ngRepeat`.

```
<a style="cursor:pointer"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': $first}" /> </a>
```

Another option is using `Descriptions.Language` and compare it to `english`.

```
<a style="cursor:pointer"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': Descriptions.Language == 'English'}" /> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat directive has a property called $first that evaluates to true if it is the first row.  Use it along with ng-if as I prefer to not have it appear, like this:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" ng-if="!$first"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': ($index == !selected)}" /> </a>
```

Otherwise, disable it like this:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': $first}" /> </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could keep English out of the loop, placing it before the loop

or

```
<div ng-repeat="Descriptions in mainsWithDescription ">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
                                <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control input-md" name="titleValidate[]" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">                             
                                <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" name="descriptionValidate[]" noresize ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <a style="cursor:pointer"><img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || mainsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-disabled="{{Descriptions.Language}}=='English'" ng-class="{'disabled': ($index == !selected)}" /> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```